# Securing PHP website to restrain opening it on other domains

Tags: php

I want to secure the PHP website so that it does not work on any other domain except the one I am working on. I can give a error page or any other website name if someone tries to configure that website on his domain. Please help here.

Thanks,
Arvind.

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 2):

You may use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to validate current domain name.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "yourdomain.com") !== -1){
    // valid case
}else{
    //redirect or throw error
}
```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the php function `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` check the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) documentation.
Let's say that only you may enter the website, you could use.

```
if ($_SERVER["REMOATE_ADDR"] == "192.168.0.111") {
  echo "Allowed";
} else {
  echo "Not allowed";
}
```